# Strings and Dynamic allocation in C

Tags: c, string

How can this code `printf()` properly although I allocated less memory than it requires.

```
char* String;
char String2[] = "testing";
String =(char*) malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(String,String2);
printf("NAME : %s",String);
```

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. Welcome to C. I'll try to find one the 100 duplicate questions.

Comment: `strcpy(String,String2);` --> What did you think should happen?

Comment: @chux segmentation fault or sth like that?

Comment: aomerk, C does is not specified to catch coding mistakes. That is one of the reasons for its execution speed.  If you want to code in a way that always catches such errors as overwriting a buffer, consider anther language and accept its  performance.